# Unable to click button using click()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute the following:

```
document.getElementById("LogInOutBtn").click();
```

OR

```
document.querySelector('#LogInOutBtn > button').click();
```

on this website: https://pm3.bigboibets.com:2053/

However, it won't click the 'Login' button.
Why isn't the code functioning?

Comment: Could you please share a minimal,verifiable code ?

Comment: The first one, because `#LogInOutBtn` is a div. Second one because they're doing something marginally tricky to disallow such behavior.

Comment: How do I get around this issue then?

Comment: You reverse-engineer how their site is working, which took me about three minutes. You trying to script kiddie their site?

Comment: I have tried to see where the event handlers lead to but couldn't find where...

Answer (score 1):

There's no click handler. Simple inspection shows `mousedown` and `mouseup` handlers. Browser debug tools are your friend; that this eluded you makes me wonder what, precisely, your goal is here, and whether or not it behooves us to help you in your endeavor.

A thirty-second Google search yielded this:

https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/trigger-an-event-11/

So you need the generic event firer from that link:

```
function triggerEvent(el, type){
   if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}
```

Then you need to generate both events:

```
triggerEvent(document.querySelector('#LogInOutBtn > button'), 'mousedown')
triggerEvent(document.querySelector('#LogInOutBtn > button'), 'mouseup')
```

Then lawyer up 'cuz you're most likely breaking their TOS.

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work with the account button in the navigation bar. I execute triggerEvent(document.querySelector('#AccountMenu'), 'mousedown')
triggerEvent(document.querySelector('#AccountMenu'), 'mouseup') I am trying this however no success, why is that?

Comment: @AnonAnon So what? You didn't ask about that.

Comment: Your function is generic to event firers so shouldn't it work with those buttons?

Comment: How would I click the navigation buttons then? Do they have hidden tags I need to reference instead?

Comment: @AnonAnon Don't know, does it?

Comment: Do I really need to make a new question for this then?

Comment: @AnonAnon I wouldn't recommend it. You're clearly attempting to do something outside what the site wants you to be able to do; SO isn't really the best option for figuring out how to hack someone's site.

Comment: It isn't malicious, I have permission from them

Comment: They don't have support with coders, it was one time project

Comment: Have to +1 simply for the "makes me wonder what, precisely, your goal is here, and whether or not it behooves us to help you in your endeavor"

Comment: Trying to create a data analyser by logging into as admin but clicking the buttons is the issue